# How to get row totals and further calculate from pandas pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I got the following dataframe using pandas pivot table

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Team','due_amount_deciles','User Category','Setteled_Status'],columns='P2P_Status',values='Unique User Id', aggfunc='count')
```

this dataframe looks like

```
                                     | P2P_Status      | Broken | f_p2p | Kept
Team | due_amount_deciles | User_cat | Setteled Status |
L1   | 0-250              | New      | pending |           12    | 1     | 65
                                       settled |           10    | 3     | 50
```

I want to find a row total which gives me Total next to Kept - pending row would give me 12+1+65 and settled row would give me 10 + 3 + 50 , I then want to calculated the % of users who broke the promise but settled the due amount and more.

Expected Dataframe

```
                                     | P2P_Status      | Broken | f_p2p | Kept | Total | BS
Team | due_amount_deciles | User_cat | Setteled Status |
L1   | 0-250              | New      | pending |           12    | 1     | 65  | 78  | -
                                       settled |           10    | 3     | 50  | 63  | 0.15
```

where BS is broken but setteled users.

How do I achieve this? is it possible in pandas?

Comment: i got the total column as user_pt["sum"] = user_pt[column_list].sum(axis=1) with column_list = list(user_pt). How do i get the second part?

Comment: Hi, could you post the output of `df.head().to_dict()` where df is you dataframe after being pivoted?